# Error Android Market

Tags: android

I was keep trying to update one of my application in Android Market. And I get this error "An unexpected error occurred. Please try again later." Does anyone know how to fix this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same some minutes ago for both saving and publishing my new app version.

Statistics are broken, too.

Seems the servers are either down for maintenance or need a restart...  ;-)

I think the problem will be fixed within the next couple of hours.

But it is annoying, anyhow! :(

Comment: Just logged out of developer console an re-logged in.
Now saving and publishing works again!
Statistics are still down reading "No Data", though. #-)

Comment: same here...you'd figure they would've hashed this type of crap out already?!